# Unity Property inspector glitched?

Tags: unity

I just updated my Unity from 4.3.3 to 4.3.4 and there is something very wrong with the Property Inspector window.
I tried restarting Unity, as well as load a different project, but neither fixed it.

This is what it looks like with a shader selected:
[image: shader in inspector]

Even an empty folder looks corrupt:
[image: folder in inspector]

Is this a known issue and is there a way to fix this?
Update1: I did a complete reinstall of 4.3.3 and the problem remained, now I am really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running Unity in DX11 mode solves the issue. It can be done by adding "-force-d3d11" at the end of the target field in shortcut properties.
It fixes the issue, along with some others, on Intel HD4xxx iGPU's.